# Java file Setting Debug points from CMD and running it using CMD

Tags: java, debugging, batch-file, cmd

I have googled and searched on Stack Overflow on

> how to set Debug points for a JAVA file using cmd and running the same
>   using cmd

but haven't got much on this topic. Can someone share some knowledge on this specific topic.

Consider I have 5 sysout statements inside the main class and I would like to have 5 break points set at each line and then execute those one by one. I need to run the class file by referencing external folder which has jar files.

I don't want to use any IDE's I want to use CMD.
I will have do setting of break points and execute the same using a batch file.

If there is a way let me know and Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use [JDB](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jdb.html)

Answer (score 1):

you can use the command tool `jdb` under the `jdk/bin` directory,this tool is used to debug application with cmd

```
public class Hello {
    public static void main(String []args) {
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }
}
```

The code above is a simple example, use the jdb debug tool follows below

```
javac -g Hello.java
```

then

```
jdb Hello
```

then

```
stop at Hello:3
```

then

```
 run
```

The application will stop at 3rd line, then you can run the app step by step!

Comment: you can get more details with the [jdb-orcale](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jdb.html)